# Adding two variables in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure why, but I am having a serious issue trying to add 1 to a variable.

```
    net = $('#net').val()+1;
$('#net').val(net).change();
```

This results in 1 1 (I understand that this is just concatenating).  The last line is to output it to my input field.  if I do this:

```
    net = net+1;
$('#net').val(net).change();
```

I get NaN.  When I try to use parseInt like this:

```
    net = net+1;
net = parseInt(net,10);
$('#net').val(net).change();
```

I still get NaN.  Ihave looked at the other examples on SO that adress this problem, and they say to use parseInt(), which I did.  What else can I try to get this to add 1 to the existing number and putit in my field?

Comment: What's the result of parseInt($('#net').val()) + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to do `net = parseInt(net,10);` first

then `net = net+1;`

In your code you do:

```
net = net+1; //from this point net=11
net = parseInt(net,10);
```

which is wrong, You should inverse your two statements

```
net = parseInt(net,10); //here net=1 (integer representation)
net = net+1; // the '+' between two integers will result in an addition and not a concatenation
```

Comment: parseInt(net, 10) is the best answer so far, because it prevents odd edge cases where strings like "011" could be interpreted as 9

Comment: This is the one that finally did the trick.  Thanks to ALL for your assistance and answers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
net = +net + 1;
$("#net").val(net);
```

The `+` in front of your net variable casts this to a `Number`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/WudHW/1/

Comment: Still get NaN.  Does the double quuotes make a difference?

Comment: @Jim keep a break point in your favourite browser developer tool and check where the problem is arising.

Comment: @Jim -- Before you do any math, can do do a quick `alert(net)` and verify that the `net` variable actually contains data?

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = parseInt($('#net').val())+1

$('#net').val(a).change();
```

this should help.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is your variable `net` is not a number but a string, you have to first parse it to an int :

```
net = parseInt($('#net').val());
```

And then do all the add you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use  [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
     net = parseInt($('#net').val())+1;
     $('#net').val(net).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because val() returns a string and you try to add 1 to a string, which contains number 1 and a space letter. Try for example

```
var net = +$.trim($('#net').val());
$('#net').val(net + 1).change();
```

This gets rid of the white space and casts net as a number before inserting it back to the input(?) field.